# Which and will together in a sentence

Tags: questions

I have a question about this sentence.
Please help me to clarify it.

"On which dates the community center will be closed ?"

Is there anything wrong in this sentence?
And what should be the correction?

Comment: What makes you think there's a problem with using *which* and *will* together in a sentence? There is, however, a problem with the syntax of your sentence. In any case, I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). You may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a question, the direct verb always gets placed second in a sentence. However, in your sentence you put *the community center*, which isn't a verb, second. So the correct sentence should read "On which dates will the community center be closed?". Note that the verb *be* is put at the end since it is an infinitive, whereas *will* is the direct verb in this sentence.